# Rotating view using constraints - Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to rotate a uiview on top of another view using constraints. Here is what I implemented

```
mediaContainer.addSubview(overlayView)
keepBottomLeft()
overlayView.layoutIfNeeded()

func keepBottomLeft(overlayView: UIView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: overlayView, attribute:.width, relatedBy:.equal,toItem: mediaContainer, attribute:.width, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: overlayView, attribute:.leading, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: mediaContainer, attribute:.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: overlayView, attribute:.height, relatedBy:.equal,toItem: nil, attribute:.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 26).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: overlayView, attribute:.bottom, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: mediaContainer, attribute:.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    overlayView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
}
```

Will it be necessary to use an anchor point? This is what I'm trying to achieve?

[image: From View A]

[image: To View B]

What I get is

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you actually want your view to rotate continuously from your first image to your second image? (So it will tilt up at an increasing diagonal until it's vertical like your second image?)

Comment: I'm not animating the rotation here. Just move to the new position on an IBAction.

Comment: Do you want the contents of the view to be rotated 90°, or just the height & width to be swapped and the anchor point adjusted?

Comment: The content too. A and B are rotated as seen in the pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anchor point is at the yellow view's center; the default.  Either you want to move it to the bottom left with layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y:1) [Note the anchor is in unit coordinates form 0 to 1, not in points]. You will still need an extra translate of x = height.

Alternatively you can concatenate your transforms and move your center to the point you want to rotate about, perform the rotation, and then reverse your translation (this is actually the typical way to do it with 3d transforms).

**UPDATE:**
Here is a playground.  Note that you concatenate the matrices in the reverse order that you want the transforms to be applied.  I have an animation in here so you can decompose the transforms and see what each one does:

1. Move the view to the origin (0,0) (this is the last transform)
2. Rotate the view 90 degrees clockwise
3. Move the view over by half of its current width and down so its at the bottom of the superview.

   ```
   import PlaygroundSupport
   import UIKit
   class V: UIViewController {
      var overlayView = UIView()
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           view.addSubview(overlayView)
           overlayView.backgroundColor = .yellow
           overlayView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26).isActive = true
           overlayView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
           overlayView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
           overlayView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       }
       override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
               let center = self.overlayView.center
               let size = self.overlayView.bounds.size
               self.overlayView.transform =
                   CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.bounds.size.height - size.width / 2, y: -size.height/2)
                   .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
                   .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -center.x, y: -center.y)))
           }
       }
   }

   let v = V()
   v.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
   PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v
   ```

Comment: After adding the constraints : 
 I tried this `overlayView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:1);
        overlayView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: overlayView.frame.size.height, y: 0)
        overlayView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))`. It bring the overlayView to the top but not close to the left edge. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: you must concatenate the matrices (i.e. multiply them together).  https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating

Comment: I tried this as well: `overlayView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: overlayView.frame.size.height, y: 0).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))) `This is what i get http://imgur.com/a/8dPpC